# Computing the geodesics on a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$ directly using orthogonality of the acceleration vector

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, geodesic

> Motivation: I am trying to understand how one in practice computes geodesics on a simple space by means of the orthogonality of the acceleration vector to the tangent space at that point. I consider a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$ and compute what I believe is the 2nd order non-linear ode that describes geodesics:

The cylinder $$C=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$$ is parametrised in $\Bbb R^3$ by:
$$\Phi(\theta,z)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,z).$$

---

A geodesic $c(t)$ of the surface has $c''(t)$ orthogonal to $T_{c(t)}C$ at each time $t$. Take a curve $$c(t) = (\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t)),z(t))$$ then we require that $c''(t)$ is orthogonal to the plane
$$\{(-\sin\theta(t)d,\cos\theta(t)d,z)\mid d,z\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R^3.$$
which means $c''(t)$ will have to be orthogonal to $$(0,0,1)\times (-\sin(\theta(t)),\cos(\theta(t)),0)= (-\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t)),0)=\mathbf{Q}$$

We compute $c''(t)$:
$$c'(t) = (-\sin(\theta(t))\dot\theta(t),\cos(\theta(t))\dot\theta(t),\dot z(t))$$
$$c''(t) = (-\cos(\theta(t))\dot\theta^2(t) -\sin(\theta(t))\ddot\theta(t), \sin(\theta(t)\dot\theta^2(t)+\cos(\theta(t))\ddot\theta(t),\ddot z(t))$$
Because this isn't in the tangent space, I would have to orthogonally project (compute covariant derivative) or otherwise check orthogonality in the ambient $\Bbb E^3$?

I think orthogonality just comes from $c''(t)\cdot \mathbf{Q}=0$: $$\cos^2(\theta(t))\dot{\theta}^2(t)+\sin(\theta(t))\cos(\theta(t))\ddot\theta(t)+\sin^2(\theta(t))\dot\theta^2(t) +\sin\theta(t)\cos(\theta(t))\ddot{\theta}(t)=0$$
$$=\dot\theta^2(t)+2\cos(\theta(t))\sin(\theta(t))\ddot\theta(t)$$

and then I just have to solve the ode:
$$\frac{d^2\theta(t)}{dt^2}(2\sin(\theta(t))\cos(\theta(t))) + \frac{d\theta(t)}{dt} = 0$$

> Am I doing this correctly? (I'll try approaching this using connections later, so I'd rather not see that form in an answer)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A cylinder is locally perfectly flat. So a geodesic is just a helix.

Comment: @TonyK My desire to compute the geodesics here isn't to know what they are, but to practice computing geodesics in general. (Although that's good to know, and I thank you for sharing your intuition!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sign mistake when computing $\ddot{c}(t)$. However, since $N:\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb R\to \Bbb S^2$ given by $N(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$ is a unit normal vector to the cylinder, we know that if $c$ is a geodesic then the tangent projection $D\dot{c}/{\rm d}t$ of $\ddot{c}(t)$ vanishes, which is to say that the latter is a multiple of $N(c(t))$ for all $t$. So we write $\ddot{c}(t)=\lambda(t)N(c(t))$ for some (automatically) smooth function $\lambda$ -- that we don't really need to solve for. So this relation becomes $$(-\sin(\theta(t))\ddot{\theta}(t)-\cos(\theta(t))\dot{\theta}(t)^2, \cos(\theta(t))\ddot{\theta}(t)-\sin(\theta(t))\dot{\theta}(t)^2,\ddot{z}(t))=\lambda(t)(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t)),0)$$Equating components and solving the system
gives $\theta(t)=at+b$ and $z(t)=ct+d$ for some constants $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb R$. If $a=c=0$ we get a point; if $a=0$ but $c\neq 0$ we get a straight vertical line. If $a\neq 0$ and $c=0$, a horizontal circle. Else, helices.

Comment: Thank you, this is massively helpful.